# Assembly graphic couldn't display right colour from array

Tags: arrays, assembly, colors, pixel

Welcome.
I could't get values from 2d array. I am trying and trying and it doesn't work. I use NASM 16 DOS

I want to have blue letter E on red backgroung. I only get square random colours.
'1' in array is blue,'4' is red. It could be spinned, but it doesn't matter.

I have no idea what is wrong. I'm trying to do this a couple od days.

Here is my code:

```
    segment .data

    segment .code
..start:
    mov ax, 13h 
    int 10h               ; switch to 320x200 mode

    mov ax, 0a000h        ; The offset to video memory
    mov es, ax            ; We load it to ES through AX,
                          ; because immediate operation
                          ; is not allowed on ES
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    mov si, T34 ; my array

    mov word [Y_Start], 10 ; Y start line count values in register
    mov word [X_Start], 20 ; X start line
    mov word [Y], 10 ; Y start line
    mov word [X], 20 ; X start line

    mov dx, 4  ; colour (red)
    mov cx, 8 ; loop top counter
    top:
        add word [Y], 1
        push cx ;loop top counter =
        mov cx, 8 ;inside loop counter
        inside:
        add word [X], 1
;//////////////////////////////////////////////      count colour
         push ax  ; remember value before procedure
         push bx
         push cx
         push dx

        mov ax, word [X]
        mov cx,8
        mul cx ;X*8 
        add ax, word[Y] ; X*8 +Y

        mov cx,4
        mul cx ; (X*8+Y)*4


        add ax, si ; tab0 + (X*8+Y)*4

        pop dx  

            mov dx,  ax; colour

            pop cx
            pop bx
            pop ax
;///////////////////////////////////////////        
        mov ax, word [Y]
        mov bx, word [X]
        push ax  ; remember value before procedure
        push bx
        push cx

        call putpixel

        pop cx  ; go back to old values
        pop bx
        pop ax
        loop inside
        mov bx, word [X_Start] ; move to X start
        mov word [X], bx       ;      

        pop cx ;loop top counter

    loop top

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    xor ah, ah
    int 16h               ; keyboard (wait for key)

    mov ax, 3
    int 10h               ; go to text mode

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h               ; return to DOS, exit code 0

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

putpixel:
    push dx               ; mul changes dx too
    mov cx, 320
    mul cx                ; multiply Y (ax) by 320 (one row)
    add ax, bx            ; and add X (bx) (result= dx:ax)
    mov di, ax
    pop dx
    mov [es:di], dx       ; store color/pixel
    ret

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

X_Start DW 0 ; start letter position
Y_Start DW 0
X DW 0 ;current letter position
Y DW 0

T34 DB 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
    DB 1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
    DB 1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
    DB 1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
    DB 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
    DB 1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
    DB 1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
    DB 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't catch your approach, but I can show you how I would do it:

```
segment .code
..start:
    mov ax, data            ; Initialize DS (needed for .exe-program)
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax, 0A000h          ; Segment to video memory
    mov es, ax

    mov ax, 13h
    int 10h                 ; Switch to 320x200 mode

    mov si, T34             ; DS:SI = letter
    mov bx, [X_Start]
    mov ax, [Y_Start]
    call vector_to_memory
    mov di, ax              ; ES:DI = video memory
    call paint

    ; once more
    add word [X_Start], 8   ; That's one small step for a man
    mov si, T34             ; DS:SI = letter
    mov bx, [X_Start]
    mov ax, [Y_Start]
    call vector_to_memory
    mov di, ax              ; ES:DI = video memory
    call paint

    xor ah, ah
    int 16h                 ; keyboard (wait for key)

    mov ax, 3
    int 10h                 ; go to text mode

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h                 ; return to DOS, exit code 0

paint:                      ; Args: DS:SI = letter, ES:DI: video memory
    mov ax, 8
    .l1:
    mov cx, 8               ; repetition count for REP
    rep movsb               ; CX times (one row): [DS:SI] => [ES:DI], SI++, DI++
    add di, (320-8)         ; next row
    sub ax, 1               ; no row left?
    jnz .l1                 ; no: once more
    ret                     ; yes: paint is done, return

vector_to_memory:           ; Args: BX = X, AX = Y
    push dx                 ; mul changes dx too
    mov cx, 320             ; video mode width
    mul cx                  ; DX:AX = AX * CX
    add ax, bx              ; left indentation
    pop dx
    ret                     ; Return: AX = offset in memory

segment .data

T34:
    DB 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
    DB 1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
    DB 1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
    DB 1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
    DB 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
    DB 1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
    DB 1,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
    DB 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1

X_Start DW 10 ; start letter position
Y_Start DW 20

segment stack stack
    resb 0x1000
```

HTH

Comment: It shows me sth like this http://pl.tinypic.com/r/jg2skp/8 . So it doesn't show letter properly to :(

Comment: Sorry, I restart my DOSbox, now I have sth like this http://pl.tinypic.com/r/11l1tvq/8. I see now it is two letters. Very thanks :)

Comment: One more thing. Could you tell me how the procedore Paint works. Vextor to memory I understand, it makes Y*320+X. And paint? It is go throught table T34 and pixel is store in line: add di, (320-8) ?

Comment: @user3797879: it copies a row (`CX` = 8 bytes) from letter to video-memory. The next row in letter begins at the next byte, but the next row in the video-memory begins (320-8) bytes later. "-8", because the current `DI` was changed by `rep movsb`. That "copying a row" is repeated 8 times (`AX`);

Answer (score 0):

You're not loading the pixel values correctly:

```
   add ax, si ; tab0 + (X*8+Y)*4

   mov dx,  ax; colour  <-- Here you're just copying the _address_, you're
                            not loading the value stored at that address.
```

Those two instructions should be changed to:

```
add si,ax
mov dl,[si]
```

Note the use of `dl` since you're dealing with bytes. I also switched the `add` around because `[ax]` wouldn't be a valid effective address. This means that you'll have to reload `si` with the address of the array on every iteration of the loop.

---

The line `mov [es:di], dx` in `putpixel` should also be changed to `mov [es:di], dl`.

---

Some of your multiplications could be simplified: to multiply a register by 4 you can do `shl reg,2`, and to multiply by 8 you can do `shl reg,3`.

Comment: I'm trying to do it like this, but the line: mov dl, [ax] does not compile. It show error: "invalid effective address"

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot about the real-mode addressing restrictions. The address has to be in `bx`, `si`, `di` or `bp`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I have changed it, but it still shows random colours. Maybe formula isn't good. I don't know.